# Store a simple table in memory in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory

Is there a simple way to store a simple table in memory on the server in ASP.NET that all users would share? Let's say I have a simple chat program for instance and I only ever want to hold the last 100 records in memory (this isn't a real application, just an example). Say I didn't want to have an entire table in SQL dedicated to being this chat buffer with only 100 records. Is there some way I could create an in-memory data table and share it among connected users?

Comment: why does it need to be a table? how about a simple `static Queue<Message>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Cache (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)

> One instance of this class is created per application domain, and it
>   remains valid as long as the application domain remains active.
>   Information about an instance of this class is available through the
>   Cache property of the HttpContext object or the Cache property of the
>   Page object.

```
DataTable yourDataTable = new DataTable();
Cache["yourTable"] = yourDataTable;

//to access it
DataTable dt = Cache["yourTable"] as DataTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HttpApplicationState` object to store things in memory and accesable for all users:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["MyTable"] = myTable;
```

Or the `Cache` object (which is more thread-safe):

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["MyTable"] = myTable;
```

Here's a good article about [Application and Cache](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/59/application-and-cache/).

> The Cache and Application objects provide broader scope than the Session object and the data is available to all the classes within the ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be a global cache. The down and dirty way to do it is to store the values is the Application state.  It is essentially a key value store that is always around as long as IIS is running.
`Application["someKey"} = SomeObject;`

you can access it the same way `

```
var myObject = Application["someKey"];`
```

There are much more elegant solutions, but that will get you by for simple global things, when you need to store small amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

you have many options, application Cache is shared among all users and all sessions within the same ASP.NET application pool, check here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.100).aspx

another option could be to use an in memory / embedded database, something like SQL Server compact or SQL Lite, depending if you really want to use a db like approach.